# VB.net Read File Name from Dir to Run SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have been asked to create a console application which polls an active Directory. (C.\Temp\Input)

When a file comes in with `(filename).SUCCESS`, filename is retrieve in order to run a SQL query. So

```
IF fileextension = SUCCESS
```

Runs SQL Query using filename to change a value in the SQL Table.
Moves Original file to `c:\temp\Input\Processed`

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

UPDATED:

Hi, With a few looks at various sites iv come up with the below. Forgetting the SQL for now, im only after the Filename and the moving of files but im getting an IO Exception that the file is already in use:

Imports System.IO
Imports System.String
Module Module1

```
Dim fileName As String = "C:\temp\Input\NR12345.success"
Dim pathname As String = "C:\temp\Input\"
Dim result As String
Dim sourceDir As String = "C:\temp\Input\"
Dim processedDir As String = "C:\temp\Input\Processed\"
Dim fList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.success")



Sub Main()
    result = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
    Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", fileName, result)
    result = Path.GetFileName(pathname)
    Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", pathname, result)

    Call MySub()

End Sub

Sub MySub()
    'Move Files

    For Each f As String In fList
        'Remove path from the file name. 
        Dim fName As String = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length = 0)
        Dim sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName)
        Dim processedFileDir = Path.Combine(processedDir, fName)

        ' Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path. 
        ' Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(processedDir, fName), True)
        'File.Copy(sourceFile, processedFileDir)

    Next f
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this before:

[The FileWather Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Really useful for polling directories for changes in structure and file details etc.

You can then use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to get an extension of a file and, if it meets your criteria, perform some actions.

These links come with examples so enjoy!!

```
Sub MySub()
    'Move Files

    For Each f As String In fList

        Dim fInfo As FileInfo = New FileInfo(f)

        Dim fName As String = fInfo.Name

        Dim processedFileDir = Path.Combine(processedDir, fName)

        ' Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path. 
        ' Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
        File.Copy(fInfo.FullName, processedFileDir, True)

    Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Your approach to data manipulations is down to how you want to do things and your RDBMS (mysql, sql-server etc) and the handling of file movement is quite simple and off the top of my head its System.IO.File.Move(sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath)

Comment: Cheers Ric, I want to connect to SQL Server and run change the status of a jobId, the ID is the filename before the extension.

Comment: Excellent Ric that's sorted that out.

Comment: Cheers. If you could mark it as the answer that will be appreciated!